# Where is Mono installing the X509 certificates in Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, x509certificate

I have a Mono application having to accept a remote X509 certificate from the server machine.

It works fine, I accept the server certificate and the communication flows but now I want to uninstall the cert from my Linux machine and I don't know how to locate it or how to remove it.

In Windows is pretty easy, I use the "certmgr.msc" and that's all... easy and fast...

How can I do the same in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the mono sources right, certificates should by default be in `~/.config/.mono/certs` but I don't have any to check.

Comment: Thanks! I found it where you said.