How can I make dotnet accept self signed CA (MITMproxy) in ubuntu (wsl2)?
I installed mitmproxy and started it - I then added it's CA certificate to the ubuntu accepted CAs (copied to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ and added to accepted with update-ca-certificates).
curl www.google.com --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080

now works without a warning.
But when I start my dotnet app (within vs code connected to wsl2) and it tries to access external APIs, I get
> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>        ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>        ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>        ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate
> chain: RevocationStatusUnknown, OfflineRevocation

(I added https_proxy: http://127.0.0.1:8080 via env variables)
Any ideas how I make sure that dotnet accepts my mitm certificate, so I can see traffic in mitmproxy?

Ubuntu provides the trusted root CA list in two formats, the one you have patched and in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt. Alternatively it is possible that Mono maintains it's own cert store https://stackoverflow.com/q/16841552/150978

so what does that mean? do I need to add it manually somewhere?
currently, it's just in that folder like this:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 21 21:01 8bbe0e8d.0 -> mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   60 Jun 21 21:01 mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/self-signed/mitmproxy-ca-cert.crt
the folder mentioned in the linked response does not exist in my .config folder
